# Fade in/out div scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, fade

I have a floating menu that i want to fade in when you start to scroll down the page, then fade out when you are back at the top of the page. I have got it working without the fade, but im not sure how to add the fades. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    $('#floatingnav').toggle($(this).scrollTop()>250)
});
```

css

```
#floatingnav {
    position:fixed;
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) with some duration as an argument(just incase you want) instead of plane toggle.That will do your job.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
     $('#floatingnav').fadeToggle($(this).scrollTop()>250)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to test if `div` has reached top

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   var d = $('div'); // this is your fixed div
    if (d.offset().top > 250) {
       d.fadeIn();
    } else {
       d.stop().fadeOut();
    }
});
```

[**TEST FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/A4J7f/3/)

Comment: Thanks, i have tried the above, however the code fades it in after scrolling, but it remains there when you scroll back up to the top. I am not using the css class margin-top, but bottom:40px; etc. Has this something to do with it?

Comment: it's probably not reaching lower than 250px from top. you may need to calculate it otherwise. or use a [waypoint plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#about)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250) {
        $("#floatingnav").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $("#floatingnav").stop().fadeOut();
    }
});
```